# On hover of single element change hover effect of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering if it is possible to activate the hover effect of multiple elements to when hovering over a single element.

Use case: I want to have a section that is colourless, greyed out. When the user scrolls over the section containing all of the greyed elements, all elements smoothly transition to the on hover colours...

Example of the effect:

[image: Example of the effect]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with CSS when you set `:hover` selector on the parent element, something like:

```css
.parent > div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.parent:hover > div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
</div>
```

If you would need to set `:hover` on the child elements for some reason, you can use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two sections have the classes section1 and section2, you can use something like:

```
    $(".section1").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            //choose what to do on hover
            this.style.setProperty('background-color','//section1 color');
            $('.section2', this)[0].style.setProperty('background-color','//section2 color');

        },
        mouseleave: function () {
             //choose what to do on mouse leave
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something similar that you are looking for

```js
children = $('.col-sm-2')
$('.col-sm-2').mouseover(function() {children.addClass('bg-danger text-white transit')})
$('.col-sm-2').mouseleave(function() {
  children.addClass('exit')
  children.removeClass('bg-danger text-white');
  
 })
```

```css
.transit {
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
.exit {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row border p-4 ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 m-1">
    Mouser over a child element below
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-2 bg-secondary rounded m-1">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2  bg-secondary rounded m-1">
    child 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2  bg-secondary rounded m-1">
    child 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2  bg-secondary rounded m-1">
    child 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2  bg-secondary rounded m-1">
    child 5
  </div>
</div>
```